# How do I find peak values/row numbers?

Tags: r, subset

I have a large dataset (202k points).  I know that there are 8 values over 0.5.  I want to subset on those rows.

How do I find/return a list the row numbers where the values are > 0.5?

Comment: You've taken the R tag off. So what language are you working in? The question can't be answered without some indication of the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the dataset is a vector named `x`:

```
(1:length(x))[x > 0.5]
```

If the dataset is a data.frame or matrix named `x` and the variable of interest is in column `j`:

```
(1:nrow(x))[x[,j] > 0.5]
```

But if you just want to find the subset and don't really need the row numbers, use

```
subset(x, x > 0.5)
```

for a vector and

```
subset(x, x[,j] > 0.5)
```

for a matrix or data.frame.

Comment: Thanks tons! that did the trick.  I kinda ended up figuring it out myself before finding out that this comment was posted, but this is exactly what I did to.

Answer (score 2):

`which(x > 0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some dummy data:

```
D<-matrix(c(0.6,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.23,0.1,0.8,0.2,0.2,0.2),nrow=3)
```

Which looks like:

```
> D
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.6  0.2 0.23  0.2
[2,]  0.1  0.1 0.10  0.2
[3,]  0.1  0.1 0.80  0.2
```

And here's the logical row index,

```
index <- (rowSums(D>0.5))>=1
```

You can use it to extract the rows you want:

```
PeakRows <- D[index,]
```

Which looks like this:

```
> PeakRows
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.6  0.2 0.23  0.2
[2,]  0.1  0.1 0.80  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the argument `arr.ind=TRUE` with `which` is a great way for finding the row (or column) numbers where a condition is `TRUE`,

```
df <- matrix(c(0.6,0.2,0.1,0.25,0.11,0.13,0.23,0.18,0.21,0.29,0.23,0.51), nrow=4)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 0.60 0.11 0.21
# [2,] 0.20 0.13 0.29
# [3,] 0.10 0.23 0.23
# [4,] 0.25 0.18 0.51
```

`which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` returns the array indices where the condition is `TRUE`

```
which(df > 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   4   3
```

so the subset becomes

```
df[-which(df > 0.5, arr.ind=TRUE)[, "row"], ]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.2 0.13 0.29
# [2,]  0.1 0.23 0.23
```